# Has anyone gotten deboostrap for jessie working from an Ubuntu host?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, software-installation, debootstrap

I am running Ubuntu 12.04, and trying to build an `armhf` Debian image for Jessie.  I've done this before for Wheezy.  The debootstap script doesn't seem to work if the target is Jessie however.  Any ideas on how to get this to work?

```
smachin@Ubuntu12_04_mq:~$ sudo debootstrap --arch=armhf --foreign $distro $targetdir
E: No such script: /usr/share/debootstrap/scripts/jessie
```

Answer (score 4):

The version of `debootstrap` in Ubuntu 12.04 is too old, it doesn't support Jessie. Support for Jessie was added in version 1.0.49.

You can upgrade to a newer version of `debootstrap` manually by downloading it from [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debootstrap); its dependencies are trivial and should be OK in Ubuntu 12.04.

Alternatively, as pointed out by [Wouter Verhelst](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/118526/wouter-verhelst), you can specify all the necessary information on the `debootstrap` command line with

```
debootstrap jessie chrootdirectory http://mirror/debian /usr/share/debootstrap/scripts/sid
```

(replacing `mirror` and `chrootdirectory` with the appropriate values), or modify your version of `debootstrap` by adding the appropriate symlink:

```
cd /usr/share/debootstrap/scripts
sudo ln -s sid jessie
```

Comment: I extracted a .deb file to get a new version of debootstrap.  If doing this, you need to set the `DEBOOTSTRAP_DIR` environment variable to point to the full path of the extracted `usr/share/debootstrap` subdirectory.